# Making GetRawInputDeviceInfo and RIDI_DEVICEINFO work with C#

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have the problem that I can't seem to make GetRawInputDeviceInfo in combination with RIDI_DEVICEINFO (to try to retrieve a RID_DEVICE_INFO) is not working at all.

I get the error -1 back from the function, what should mean that there is not enough space to store the RID_DEVICE_INFO, buy I tried already to increase it to the more then needed but the effect the same.

I used the following DLLImports :

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
extern static uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize);

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
unsafe extern static uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, IntPtr pcbSize);
```

Both with no result, but when I try these with RIDI_DEVICENAME they both work just fine.
In this case I call the function like this :

first to get the size: `GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, IntPtr.Zero, pSize);`

and then : `GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, pData, pSize);`

to get the name. Both work fine, but when I call the function like this :

```
int intReturn = (int)GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICEINFO, IntPtr.Zero, pInfoSize);
intReturn = (int)GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICEINFO, pInfoData, pInfoSize);
```

Then at first I get 0 into intReturn and also can get the correct size,
but then I get -1 into return, and whan I do a PtrToStructure it just returns wrong and seemingly random values.

Also when I after that do a GetLastWin32Error(), it return sometime 1008 or 87 , what also seems not to make any logic to me, because I don't see where I could have made the wrong parameters.

I defined RIDI_DEVICENAME and RIDI_DEVICEINFO  as :

```
internal const uint RIDI_DEVICENAME = 0x20000007;
internal const uint RIDI_DEVICEINFO = 0x2000000b;
```

Can anyone help with this problem or show me a working C# example for GetRawInputDeviceInfo ?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What exception are you getting from this code?And which version of .net are you using?

Comment: I have exactly this problem, but calling inside a native C DLL. My code works perfectly under Windows 7, but fails with the same error code as yours on XP. I believe this is a RawInput problem, not a .NET problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have it working in Windows 8.1 x64 (let me know if I have missed an enum or struct somewhere):

```
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves information about the raw input device.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hDevice">A handle to the raw input device. This comes from the lParam of the WM_INPUT message, from the hDevice member of RAWINPUTHEADER, or from GetRawInputDeviceList. It can also be NULL if an application inserts input data, for example, by using SendInput.</param>
/// <param name="uiCommand">Specifies what data will be returned in pData.</param>
/// <param name="pData">A pointer to a buffer that contains the information specified by uiCommand. If uiCommand is RIDI_DEVICEINFO, set the cbSize member of RID_DEVICE_INFO to sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO) before calling GetRawInputDeviceInfo. </param>
/// <param name="pcbSize">The size, in bytes, of the data in pData. </param>
/// <returns>If successful, this function returns a non-negative number indicating the number of bytes copied to pData. If pData is not large enough for the data, the function returns -1. If pData is NULL, the function returns a value of zero. In both of these cases, pcbSize is set to the minimum size required for the pData buffer. Call GetLastError to identify any other errors.</returns>
/// <remarks>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645597%28v=vs.85%29.aspx</remarks>
[DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(
    [In] IntPtr hDevice,
    [In] RawInputDeviceInformationCommand uiCommand,
    [In, Out] IntPtr pData,
    [In, Out] ref uint pcbSize);

public enum RawInputDeviceInformationCommand : int
{
    /// <summary>
    /// pData points to a string that contains the device name. For this uiCommand only, the value in pcbSize is the character count (not the byte count).
    /// </summary>
    RIDI_DEVICENAME = 0x20000007,
    /// <summary>
    /// pData points to an RID_DEVICE_INFO structure.
    /// </summary>
    RIDI_DEVICEINFO = 0x2000000b,
    /// <summary>
    /// pData points to the previously parsed data.
    /// </summary>
    RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA = 0x20000005
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct RID_DEVICE_INFO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The size, in bytes, of the RID_DEVICE_INFO structure. 
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int cbSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of raw input data.
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public RawInputDeviceType dwType;
    /// <summary>
    /// If dwType is RIM_TYPEMOUSE, this is the RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE structure that defines the mouse. 
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE mouse;
    /// <summary>
    /// If dwType is RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD, this is the RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD structure that defines the keyboard. 
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD keyboard;
    /// <summary>
    /// If dwType is RIM_TYPEHID, this is the RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID structure that defines the HID device. 
    /// </summary>
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID hid;
}
/// <summary>
/// Defines the raw input data coming from the specified mouse.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx</remarks>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_MOUSE
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The identifier of the mouse device.
    /// </summary>
    public int dwId;
    /// <summary>
    /// The number of buttons for the mouse.
    /// </summary>
    public int dwNumberOfButtons;
    /// <summary>
    /// The number of data points per second. This information may not be applicable for every mouse device.
    /// </summary>
    public int dwSampleRate;
    /// <summary>
    /// TRUE if the mouse has a wheel for horizontal scrolling; otherwise, FALSE.
    /// Windows XP:  This member is only supported starting with Windows Vista.
    /// </summary>
    public bool fHasHorizontalWheel;
}
/// <summary>
/// Defines the raw input data coming from the specified keyboard. 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx</remarks>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the keyboard. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwType;
    /// <summary>
    /// The subtype of the keyboard. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwSubType;
    /// <summary>
    /// The scan code mode. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwKeyboardMode;
    /// <summary>
    /// The number of function keys on the keyboard.
    /// </summary>
    public int dwNumberOfFunctionKeys;
    /// <summary>
    /// The number of LED indicators on the keyboard.
    /// </summary>
    public int dwNumberOfIndicators;
    /// <summary>
    /// The total number of keys on the keyboard. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwNumberOfKeysTotal;
}
/// <summary>
/// Defines the raw input data coming from the specified Human Interface Device (HID). 
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx</remarks>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RID_DEVICE_INFO_HID
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The vendor identifier for the HID. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwVendorId;
    /// <summary>
    /// The product identifier for the HID. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwProductId;
    /// <summary>
    /// The version number for the HID. 
    /// </summary>
    public int dwVersionNumber;
    /// <summary>
    /// The top-level collection Usage Page for the device. 
    /// </summary>
    public ushort usUsagePage;
    /// <summary>
    /// The top-level collection Usage for the device. 
    /// </summary>
    public ushort usUsage;
}
/// <summary>
/// The type of raw input data.
/// </summary>
public enum RawInputDeviceType : int
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Data comes from a mouse.
    /// </summary>
    RIM_TYPEMOUSE = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// Data comes from a keyboard.
    /// </summary>
    RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD = 1,
    /// <summary>
    /// Data comes from an HID that is not a keyboard or a mouse.
    /// </summary>
    RIM_TYPEHID = 2,
}
//somewhere in your code:
IntPtr pData = IntPtr.Zero;
uint strsize = 0;
IntPtr deviceHandle = <your device handle here>;
result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(deviceHandle, RawInputDeviceInformationCommand.RIDI_DEVICENAME, pData, ref strsize);
pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(((int)strsize)*2);
result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(deviceHandle, RawInputDeviceInformationCommand.RIDI_DEVICENAME, pData, ref strsize);
Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result + " ErrorCode = " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
string name = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pData);
Console.WriteLine("Name = " + name);
uint structsize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO));
RID_DEVICE_INFO di = new RID_DEVICE_INFO();
di.cbSize = (int)structsize;
pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)structsize);
result = GetRawInputDeviceInfo(deviceHandle, RawInputDeviceInformationCommand.RIDI_DEVICEINFO, pData, ref structsize);
di = (RID_DEVICE_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pData, typeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO));
Console.WriteLine("di.dwType = " + Enum.GetName(typeof(RawInputDeviceType), di.dwType));
switch (di.dwType)
{
    case RawInputDeviceType.RIM_TYPEHID:
        Console.WriteLine("di.hid.dwVendorId = " + di.hid.dwVendorId);
        Console.WriteLine("di.hid.dwProductId = " + di.hid.dwProductId);
        Console.WriteLine("di.hid.dwVersionNumber = " + di.hid.dwVersionNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("di.hid.usUsagePage = " + di.hid.usUsagePage);
        Console.WriteLine("di.hid.usUsage = " + di.hid.usUsage);
        break;
    case RawInputDeviceType.RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD:
        Console.WriteLine("di.keyboard.dwType = " + di.keyboard.dwType);
        Console.WriteLine("di.keyboard.dwSubType = " + di.keyboard.dwSubType);
        Console.WriteLine("di.keyboard.dwNumberOfFunctionKeys = " + di.keyboard.dwNumberOfFunctionKeys);
        Console.WriteLine("di.keyboard.dwNumberOfIndicators = " + di.keyboard.dwNumberOfIndicators);
        Console.WriteLine("di.keyboard.dwNumberOfKeysTotal = " + di.keyboard.dwNumberOfKeysTotal);
        break;
    case RawInputDeviceType.RIM_TYPEMOUSE:
        Console.WriteLine("di.mouse.dwId = " + di.mouse.dwId);
        Console.WriteLine("di.mouse.dwNumberOfButtons = " + di.mouse.dwNumberOfButtons);
        Console.WriteLine("di.mouse.dwSampleRate = " + di.mouse.dwSampleRate);
        Console.WriteLine("di.mouse.fHasHorizontalWheel = " + di.mouse.fHasHorizontalWheel);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: One minor thing: `GetRawInputDeviceInfo(deviceHandle, RawInputDeviceInformationCommand.RIDI_DEVICENAME, pData, ref strsize);` sets strsize to the size in **characters**, not bytes, so you need to do `pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)strsize*2);` after that instead of `pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)strsize);` or you might get a crash.