# GetRawInputDeviceInfo indicates a buffer size of 1 character for RIDI_DEVICENAME

Tags: winapi, input, raw-input

I'm getting ridiculous behavior from `RIDI_DEVICENAME`.  According to the documentation,

> ## Return value
>
> Type: `UINT`
>
> If successful, this function returns a non-negative number indicating the number of bytes copied to `pData`.
>
> If `pData` is not large enough for the data, the function returns `-1`. If `pData` is `NULL`, the function returns a value of zero. In both of these cases, `pcbSize` is set to the minimum size required for the `pData` buffer.
>
> Call `GetLastError` to identify any other errors.

Ignoring the obvious problem that `-1` is not a representable value in the `UINT` return type, it seems that the function should tell me the required size of the buffer, and if I supply a buffer of this size, the function should either succeed or at least follow its own rules for failure.

However, I'm not seeing this at all.  On Windows 10, the Unicode version of the function sets `pcbSize` to `1` when `pData` is null and leaves it alone otherwise, failing in all cases.  The ANSI version of the function sets `pcbSize` to `2` when `pData` is null, and otherwise doubles whatever value was passed in, and still fails.

Headers used for either version of test code:

```
#define WIN32_EXTRA_LEAN 1

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <windows.h>
```

ANSI test code:

```
std::string GetRawInputDeviceName( HANDLE hRaw )
{
    UINT numChars = 0u;
    INT validChars;

    validChars = static_cast<INT>(::GetRawInputDeviceInfoA(hRaw, RIDI_DEVICENAME, nullptr, &numChars));
    auto lasterror = ::GetLastError();
    if (lasterror != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to get length of name of raw input device, retcode = " << validChars << L", last error = " << lasterror << L"\n";
        return {};
    }

    std::string name;
    name.resize(numChars);
    validChars = static_cast<INT>(::GetRawInputDeviceInfoA(hRaw, RIDI_DEVICENAME, &name[0], &numChars));
    lasterror = ::GetLastError();

    if (validChars > 0) {
        name.resize(validChars);
        return name;
    }
    else {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to get name of raw input device, retcode = " << validChars << L", last error = " << lasterror << L"\n";
        return {};
    }
}
```

Unicode test code:

```
std::wstring GetRawInputDeviceName( HANDLE hRaw )
{
    UINT numChars = 0u;
    INT validChars;

    validChars = static_cast<INT>(::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(hRaw, RIDI_DEVICENAME, nullptr, &numChars));
    auto lasterror = ::GetLastError();
    if (lasterror != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to get length of name of raw input device, retcode = " << validChars << L", last error = " << lasterror << L"\n";
        return {};
    }

    std::wstring name;
    name.resize(numChars);
    validChars = static_cast<INT>(::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(hRaw, RIDI_DEVICENAME, &name[0], &numChars));
    lasterror = ::GetLastError();

    if (validChars > 0) {
        name.resize(validChars);
        return name;
    }
    else {
        std::wcerr << L"Failed to get name of raw input device, retcode = " << validChars << L", last error = " << lasterror << L"\n";
        return {};
    }
}
```

On Windows 10 through RDP I'm getting `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` consistently.

On Windows 8.1 running as a local user, I get `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` if `pData` is null, and when I provide a buffer I get back failure (`(UINT)-1`) and `GetLastError()` returns zero.

I've also just tried proposing a likely-large-enough buffer size, and got failures as well.

What is going on, what is the right way to get the interface path name, and do I need administrative rights or to call some other APIs first?  I don't seem to be having any problems calling `GetRawInputDeviceList` or using `RIDI_DEVICEINFO` mode of `GetRawInputDeviceInfo`... but I need the interface path in order to go further.

- [Windows HID Device Name Format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12656236/103167)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/64320052/103167

Comment: yes, really mistake in this api. it work ok for local devices, but as you note - `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` and wrong data in *cbSize* for virtual erd mouse/keyboard.

Comment: what is wrong in your code - you call/check *GetLastError* unconditionally after *GetRawInputDeviceInfoW*, when api set last error only in case *(UINT)-1* returned. in other case - value of *GetLastError* is random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `GetRawInputDeviceName` have several errors in declaration / implementation / documentation

by fact more correct declare return value as signed ( `LONG` or `INT`) but not UINT

exist 3 case:

**1.** function return negative value (or if want `-1`) : this is error
case, and by design - last error must be set. but really it not
always set (implementation error).

most common errors:

- *pcbSize* or *pData* point to invalid or read only memory location. usual error in this case `ERROR_NOACCESS` (translated from
  `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`)
- *hDevice* not valid handle - `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` is returned
- *uiCommand* not valid *RIDI_XXX* constant - `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`
- **pcbSize* is not large enough for the data - in this case **pcbSize* is set to the minimum size required for the pData buffer. `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`

  again - only in this case (`-1`) exist sense call `GetLastError();`

**2.** function return 0 this possible only in case when *pData* is *NULL*.
**pcbSize* is set to the minimum size required for the pData buffer.

**3.** function return positive value ( > 0)  this mean that this count of
bytes (in case `RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA` or `RIDI_DEVICEINFO` ) or
**characters** (in case `RIDI_DEVICENAME`) written to buffer

so documentation is wrong here:

> *pcbSize*
> *[in, out]*
>
> Pointer to a variable that contains the size, in bytes, of the data in
> *pData*.

in case `RIDI_DEVICENAME` in **characters**

so already visible very serious problems with design (type of return value - unsigned) and mixed bytes/characters. many different cases.

but then exist critical error in implementation. in begin of function handle *hDevice* converted to pointer.

`PDEVICEINFO pDeviceInfo = HMValidateHandle(hDevice, TYPE_DEVICEINFO);`

(if 0 returned - we got -1 on exit with `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`).

in `DEVICEINFO` exist `UNICODE_STRING ustrName` - this name and copied to user mode

```
switch (uiCommand) {
case RIDI_DEVICENAME:
    /*
     * N.b. UNICODE_STRING counts the length by the BYTE count, not by the character count.
     * Our APIs always treat the strings by the character count. Thus, for RIDI_DEVICNAME
     * only, cbOutSize holds the character count, not the byte count, in spite of its
     * name. Confusing, but cch is the way to be consistent.
     */
    cbOutSize = pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Length / sizeof(WCHAR) + 1;   // for Null terminator
    break;

   //...
}
```

required `cbOutSize` compared with `cbBufferSize = *pcbSize;`

and `if (cbBufferSize >= cbOutSize)` api begin copy operation

exist next code

```
            case RIDI_DEVICENAME:
                if (cbOutSize <= 2) { // !!!! error !!!!
                    retval = -1;
                    goto leave;
                }
                RtlCopyMemory(pData, pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Buffer, pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Length);
                ((WCHAR*)pData)[1] = '\\'; // convert nt prefix ( \??\ ) to win32 ( \\?\ )
                ((WCHAR*)pData)[cbOutSize - 1] = 0; // make it null terminated
                break;
```

*cbOutSize* here - is *(len + 1)* of device name (which we not control). so if name is zero length - always `-1` is returned (*error #1*) but last error not set ( *error #2* )
of course exist and *error #3* - why is device name is 0 length ? this must not be. but in case terminal service devices - (virtual mouse/ keyboard device created on UMB bus ) - exist this result.

full code for api ( in kernel)

```
UINT NtUserGetRawInputDeviceInfo(
    HANDLE hDevice,
    UINT uiCommand,
    LPVOID pData,
    PUINT pcbSize)
{
    UINT cbOutSize = 0;
    UINT cbBufferSize;
    int retval = 0;

    EnterCrit(0, UserMode);
    UserAtomicCheck uac;

    try {
        ProbeForRead(pcbSize, sizeof(UINT), sizeof(DWORD));
        cbBufferSize = *pcbSize;
    } except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
       UserSetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError(GetExceptionCode()));// ERROR_NOACCESS    
       retval = -1;
       goto leave1;
    }

    EnterDeviceInfoListCrit_();

    PDEVICEINFO pDeviceInfo = HMValidateHandle(hDevice, TYPE_DEVICEINFO);

    if (pDeviceInfo == NULL) {
        UserSetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE); 
        retval = -1;
        goto leave;
    }

    /*
     * Compute the size of the output and evaluate the uiCommand.
     */
    switch (uiCommand) {
    case RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA:
        if (pDeviceInfo->type == DEVICE_TYPE_HID) {
            cbOutSize = pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->hidCollectionInfo.DescriptorSize;
        } else {
            cbOutSize = 0;
        }
        break;
    case RIDI_DEVICENAME:
        /*
         * N.b. UNICODE_STRING counts the length by the BYTE count, not by the character count.
         * Our APIs always treat the strings by the character count. Thus, for RIDI_DEVICNAME
         * only, cbOutSize holds the character count, not the byte count, in spite of its
         * name. Confusing, but cch is the way to be consistent.
         */
        cbOutSize = pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Length / sizeof(WCHAR) + 1;   // for Null terminator
        break;

    case RIDI_DEVICEINFO:
        cbOutSize = sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO);
        break;

    default:
        UserSetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);  
        retval = -1;
        goto leave;
    }

    if (pData == NULL) {
        /*
         * The app wants to get the required size.
         */
        try {
            ProbeForWrite(pcbSize, sizeof(UINT), sizeof(DWORD));
            *pcbSize = cbOutSize;
        } except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
            UserSetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError(GetExceptionCode()));// ERROR_NOACCESS   
            retval = -1;
            goto leave;
        }
        retval = 0;
    } else {
        if (cbBufferSize >= cbOutSize) {
            try {
                ProbeForWrite(pData, cbBufferSize, sizeof(DWORD));
                switch (uiCommand) {
                case RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA:
                    if (pDeviceInfo->type == DEVICE_TYPE_HID) {
                        RtlCopyMemory(pData, pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->pPreparsedData, cbOutSize);
                    }
                    break;

                case RIDI_DEVICENAME:
                    if (cbOutSize <= 2) { // !!!!
                        retval = -1;
                        goto leave;
                    }
                    RtlCopyMemory(pData, pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Buffer, pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Length);
                    ((WCHAR*)pData)[1] = '\\'; // make it null terminated
                    ((WCHAR*)pData)[cbOutSize - 1] = 0; // make it null terminated
                    break;

                case RIDI_DEVICEINFO:
                    {
                        PRID_DEVICE_INFO prdi = (PRID_DEVICE_INFO)pData;

                        ProbeForRead(prdi, sizeof(UINT), sizeof(DWORD));
                        if (prdi->cbSize != cbOutSize) {
                            MSGERRORCLEANUP(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
                        }
                        ProbeForWrite(prdi, sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO), sizeof(DWORD));
                        RtlZeroMemory(prdi, sizeof(RID_DEVICE_INFO));
                        prdi->cbSize = cbOutSize;

                        switch (pDeviceInfo->type) {
                        case DEVICE_TYPE_HID:
                            prdi->dwType = RIM_TYPEHID;
                            prdi->hid.dwVendorId = pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->hidCollectionInfo.VendorID;
                            prdi->hid.dwProductId = pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->hidCollectionInfo.ProductID;
                            prdi->hid.dwVersionNumber = pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->hidCollectionInfo.VersionNumber;
                            prdi->hid.usUsagePage = pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->hidpCaps.UsagePage;
                            prdi->hid.usUsage = pDeviceInfo->hid.pHidDesc->hidpCaps.Usage;
                            break;

                        case DEVICE_TYPE_MOUSE:
                            prdi->dwType = RIM_TYPEMOUSE;
                            prdi->mouse.dwId = pDeviceInfo->mouse.Attr.MouseIdentifier;
                            prdi->mouse.dwNumberOfButtons = pDeviceInfo->mouse.Attr.NumberOfButtons;
                            prdi->mouse.dwSampleRate = pDeviceInfo->mouse.Attr.SampleRate;
                            break;

                        case DEVICE_TYPE_KEYBOARD:
                            prdi->dwType = RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD;
                            prdi->keyboard.dwType = GET_KEYBOARD_DEVINFO_TYPE(pDeviceInfo);
                            prdi->keyboard.dwSubType = GET_KEYBOARD_DEVINFO_SUBTYPE(pDeviceInfo);
                            prdi->keyboard.dwKeyboardMode = pDeviceInfo->keyboard.Attr.KeyboardMode;
                            prdi->keyboard.dwNumberOfFunctionKeys = pDeviceInfo->keyboard.Attr.NumberOfFunctionKeys;
                            prdi->keyboard.dwNumberOfIndicators = pDeviceInfo->keyboard.Attr.NumberOfIndicators;
                            prdi->keyboard.dwNumberOfKeysTotal = pDeviceInfo->keyboard.Attr.NumberOfKeysTotal;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    __assume(false);
                }
            } except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
                UserSetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError(GetExceptionCode()));// ERROR_NOACCESS   
                retval = -1;
                goto leave;
            }
            retval = cbOutSize;
        } else {
            /*
             * The buffer size is too small.
             * Returns error, storing the required size in *pcbSize.
             */
            retval = -1;
            try {
                ProbeForWrite(pcbSize, sizeof(UINT), sizeof(DWORD));
                *pcbSize = cbOutSize;
                UserSetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
            } except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
                UserSetLastError(RtlNtStatusToDosError(GetExceptionCode()));// ERROR_NOACCESS   
                retval = -1;
                goto leave;
            }
        }
    }

leave:
    LeaveDeviceInfoListCrit_();
leave1:
    UserSessionSwitchLeaveCrit();

    return retval;
}
```

then `GetRawInputDeviceInfoA` add additional errors compare `GetRawInputDeviceInfoW` - the value from **pcbSize* by some reason multiple on 2. but again - this error in all case.
note that DeviceName (formatted from strings returned from driver on [`IRP_MN_QUERY_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/irp-mn-query-id) have very strict restrictions:

> If a driver returns an ID with an illegal character, the system will
> bug check. Characters with the following values are illegal in an ID
> for this IRP:
>
> - Less than or equal to 0x20 (' ')
> - Greater than 0x7F
> - Equal to 0x2C (',')

so even after covert unicode to ansi - length of device name will be the same ( all symbols < *0x80* ). so not need `*2` buffer size for Ansi version.

---

then i already view error in your code - you call `::GetLastError();` unconditionally after `GetRawInputDeviceInfoW` - but returned value have sense only in case api return `-1`

explain for observed behavior:

for local devices api in general work correct (if no mistakes in our code)
for terminal service devices - was 0 length `ustrName`. as result if we pass *NULL* in *pData* - return value will be

```
pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Length / sizeof(WCHAR) + 1;
```

because `pDeviceInfo->ustrName.Length == 0` - 1 will be returned inside **pcbSize*
in case *A* version - -by mistake - `2*1==2` will be returned.
but when e pass not *NULL* in *pData* - we trap in this

```
            if (cbOutSize <= 2) { // !!!! error !!!!
                retval = -1;
                goto leave;
            }
```

so you can pass any by size buffer, anyway, because `(cbOutSize <= 2)` - `-1` will be returned and last error **not set**

---

possible solution - at first - never use ansi version - `GetRawInputDeviceInfoA`

use this wrapper function.

```
ULONG GetRawInputDeviceInfoExW(_In_opt_ HANDLE hDevice, 
                               _In_ UINT uiCommand, 
                               _Inout_updates_bytes_to_opt_(*pcbSize, *pcbSize) LPVOID pData, 
                               _Inout_ PUINT pcbSize)
{
    switch (int i = GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(hDevice, uiCommand, pData, pcbSize))
    {
    case 0:
        return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
    case 1:
        return ERROR_INVALID_NAME;
    default:
        if (0 > i)
        {
            return GetLastError();
        }
        *pcbSize = i;

        return NOERROR;
    }
}
```

example of usage: (`/RTCs` must be disabled )

```
void Demo()
{
    PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList = 0;
    UINT uiNumDevices = 0; 
    UINT cch, cchAllocated = 0;
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PWSTR name;
    };

    buf = 0;

    while (0 <= (int)GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &uiNumDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)))
    {
        if (pRawInputDeviceList)
        {
            do 
            {
                HANDLE hDevice = pRawInputDeviceList->hDevice;

                ULONG dwError;
                while (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (dwError = 
                    GetRawInputDeviceInfoExW(hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, name, &(cch = cchAllocated))))
                {
                    if (cch > cchAllocated)
                    {
                        cchAllocated = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca((cch - cchAllocated) * sizeof(WCHAR)), 
                            pRawInputDeviceList) / sizeof(WCHAR);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        __debugbreak();
                    }
                }

                if (dwError == NOERROR)
                {
                    DbgPrint("[%p, %x %S]\n", hDevice, pRawInputDeviceList->dwType, name);
                }
                else
                {
                    DbgPrint("error = %u\n", dwError);
                }

            } while (pRawInputDeviceList++, --uiNumDevices);

            break;
        }
        pRawInputDeviceList = (PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST)alloca(uiNumDevices * sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see by my usage of `std::wstring`, I'm already measuring everything in characters for `RIDI_DEVICENAME`.  I've never seen `ERROR_NOACCESS` or `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` or `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

Comment: I call `::GetLastError()` immediately to make sure I capture it before anything else changes it (like usage of `std::cerr`).  But I only check the return value when the function returned 0 or -1.  You're imagining a bug there.

Comment: I did suspect that things might be strange in RDP environment, so I also directly ran on the computer I'm making the RDP connection from. but even if the string is zero-length the function still shouldn't fail it should tell me it needs one character (for NUL) and then when I give it space for one character it should succeed.  But it does not.

Comment: Thank you for finding the `if (cbOutSize <= 2)` in the underlying code, I will update my code to force a larger buffer.

Comment: @BenVoigt - *I've never seen ERROR_NOACCESS..* may be i bad explain.. i simply in general explain what errors can return this api and under what condition. *if (lasterror != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)* i view this in your code - so you unconditionally check last error before check return value. and *immediately to make sure I capture it before anything else changes* - this is not mandatory. last error can be changed only as result some winapi call - direct or indirect. if you use only compiler internal constructions - this not call winapi and not change last error of course

Comment: The first call I pass NULL as the pointer, the call will always fail, I can unconditionally call `::GetLastError()` here.  And it does in fact always return `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` this time.  But it sets *pcbSize to `1`.

Comment: @BenVoigt *Thank you for finding the if (cbOutSize <= 2) in the underlying code, I will update my code to force a larger buffer* - i afraid you not understand me. the *cbOutSize* - this is size of *ustrName* inside *DEVICEINFO* - you not control this. your size - is in *cbBufferSize* - so you can not avoid error here. with any buffer size

Comment: However even after forcing the buffer to be at least `4` characters even if the first call requested only `1`, the second call still errors.

Comment: After your new comment that makes sense.  So if the first call gives a size less than or equal to `2` it is a fatal error, the name is not available.  I can code for that, thanks.

Comment: @BenVoigt - *the second call still errors* - this and must be. error in api implementation. may be my pure english - or i just bad explain

Comment: Actually since a valid result *must* begin with ``\\?\`` I suppose any buffer size less than 5 is an immediate sign of an error.

Comment: @BenVoigt - *The first call I pass NULL as the pointer, the call will always fail, I can unconditionally call ::GetLastError() here.* - this is error from your side and UB by fact. in this case (*pData == 0) - api **not set last error**. so you got **random value** after call `GetLastError`

Comment: this api set last error only in case it return -1 (and not always by mistake). if it return other value - last error code is random from the past error

Comment: @RbMb: Sorry incomplete explanation.  First call I always pass null pointer **and zero as the length**.  This is legal, not UB, and always results in failure return value of `0` and last error of `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`.

Comment: @BenVoigt - no, afraid you not understand me. the api **not change/not set** last error value in this case. so what you check ? random value

Comment: BTW calling `::GetLastError()` is *never* UB.  It can be an unrelated value, but always legal to call at any time.

Comment: @BenVoigt - yes,but why you not understand me ? of course we at any time can call `GetLastError()`. but check  *unrelated value* and based on this check - this is UB

Comment: @BenVoigt - you can do very simply test. call `SetLastError(0x1234);
 GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, 0, pcbSize);
 GetLastError();` - what value will be returned by `GetLastError()` here ? (if *pcbSize* and *hDevice* is correct)

Comment: (if *pcbSize* will be wrong you got *ERROR_NOACCESS*, if *hDevice* will be wrong - you got *ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE* - here i simply explain api logic). but if this params correct - *GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, 0, pcbSize);* not change last error code. as result you check *unrelated value* in begin of your function. this is *UB* (but not call to `GetLastError()`). and how i say at begin - not mandatory "just" call `GetLastError` after api call. we can first check function return value and only after this

Comment: Ok it's a bug (but it is NOT undefined behavior, comparing the error code before the function runs when you meant to check the error code after the function runs does not break any rules of C++).  My final code won't do that.  My initial code didn't do that either, until I ran into the bugs inside the API and increased the error checking a lot.

Comment: I am finally getting reasonable values when not running through RDP, so thank you.

Comment: @BenVoigt - i think we simply different mean here under *UB*. of course this is not from *c++* view i mean. i simply try say - that you got *lasterror* - not as result of call *GetRawInputDeviceInfoW* but - from some random and another code, which is executed before in your process. so here can be any value.

Comment: That is an "unspecified value" not "undefined behavior".  It still is an ordinary numeric value (no exceptions, no CPU traps, etc.)  So my code could take an unwanted branch, but no nasal demons.

Comment: @BenVoigt - i not sure what is joke here (all or part :) ). ok - i mean "unspecified value" all time.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine on my PC. Not sure, but it indeed could be RDP issue.

```cpp
UINT result = ::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(m_Handle, RIDI_DEVICENAME, nullptr, &size);
if (result == static_cast<UINT>(-1))
{
    //PLOG(ERROR) << "GetRawInputDeviceInfo() failed";
    return false;
}
DCHECK_EQ(0u, result);

std::wstring buffer(size, 0);
result = ::GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(m_Handle, RIDI_DEVICENAME, buffer.data(), &size);
if (result == static_cast<UINT>(-1))
{
    //PLOG(ERROR) << "GetRawInputDeviceInfo() failed";
    return false;
}
DCHECK_EQ(size, result);
```