# HidD_* functions all fail due to an invalid HID handle (Windows HID C++ API)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, hid

I am having issues getting usage data from a Windows Precision Touchpad in my C++ desktop application. I have gotten the following working:

- Registered for raw input
- I am receiving WM_INPUT messages containing raw data
- I can call `GetRawInputData()` to return a `RAWINPUT` structure

My next step has been trying to use the `Hidpi.h` utilities to determine which usages my touchpad support (`HidP_GetCaps(), HidP_GetValueCaps(), etc...`), and then get their values. To get things going, I am simply trying to print X, Y, tip switch, contact id, and max contact count).

In order to use the aforementioned utilities, I noticed from documentation that I generally need 2 things: Preparsed data (`PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA`) and the actual Input or Feature Report.

This is where things started going wrong. Everything I have read said I should have been able to use `HidD_GetPreparsedData()` to get the first item. The HID device handle I'm passing is `raw_data_buffer->header.hDevice`, where raw_data_buffer is the `PRAWINPUT` type I populated from `GetRawInputData()`. Unfortunately, this fails. Calling `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. I was unable to find any explanation...the handle wasn't NULL and matched the HID device I was trying to read from.

I found a different method to get the preparsed data:

```
...
preparsed_data_buffer = (PHIDP_PREPARSED_DATA)malloc( pp_data_buf_sz );
GetRawInputDeviceInfo( raw_data_buffer->header.hDevice, RIDI_PREPARSEDDATA, preparsed_data_buffer, &pp_data_buf_sz );
...
```

As far as I can tell, the data is correct. I was able to then able to use `*_GetCaps()` and `_*GetValueCaps()` to see supported usages.

```
11 Input Button Capabilites Found
Index:   0, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0042
Index:   1, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0047
Index:   2, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0042
Index:   3, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0047
Index:   4, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0042
Index:   5, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0047
Index:   6, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0042
Index:   7, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0047
Index:   8, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0042
Index:   9, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0047
Index:  10, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0009, Usage: 0X0001

17 Input Value Capabilites Found
Index:   0, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0051
Index:   1, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0030
Index:   2, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0031
Index:   3, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0051
Index:   4, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0030
Index:   5, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0031
Index:   6, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0051
Index:   7, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0030
Index:   8, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0031
Index:   9, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0051
Index:  10, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0030
Index:  11, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0031
Index:  12, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0051
Index:  13, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0030
Index:  14, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X0001, Usage: 0X0031
Index:  15, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0056
Index:  16, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0054

3 Feature Value Capabilites Found
Index:   0, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0059
Index:   1, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0X000D, Usage: 0X0055
Index:   2, IsRange: 0, UsagePage: 0XFF00, Usage: 0X00C5
```

I found everything I expected. X (x1/x30), Y (x1/x31), and Contact ID (xD/x51) should be in my Input Report, the Tip Switch would be a button, and Max Contact Count (xD/x55) would be in my Feature Value Report.

Focusing on the Input/Feature reports next, I am running into my original problem. The 7th parameter to `HidP_GetUsageValue()` is a `PCHAR` to either the input or feature reports, but I don't know how to get them. `HidD_GetInputReport()` and `HidD_GetFeature()` both fail with the same invalid handle error I was seeing trying to get the preparsed data through that API.

After going through probably 10 threads or examples, I noticed somebody using their raw (unparsed) data to get input values as such:

```
HidP_GetUsageValue( HidP_Input, usages[ usage_idx ].page, 0, usages[ usage_idx ].usage, &val,
                    preparsed_data, (PCHAR)raw_data_buffer->data.hid.bRawData, hid_capabilities.InputReportByteLength );
```

This worked. I can get x, y, and contact ids from the input report...I guess because the raw input report must be the first block of raw data. However, I still can't get the feature report using `HidP_GetUsageValue( HidP_Feature...` because I don't know where that report is in the raw input.

I have spent over 10 hours researching for possible causes and workarounds, and have come up with nothing. For the purposes of my application I might be able to get away with just the Input Report values, but there has to be something I'm missing.

6/14 UPDATE:
@RbMm @psmears Thank you for your comments. I didn't realize that the return from `GetRawInputDeviceInfo()`, using `RIDI_DEVICENAME`, was the symbolic path needed to create a file for my device. I didn't need to use SetupApi or cfgmgr32 to go through all the device interfaces. I'm still unable to create a file for my device though. Since I can see the path I'm looking for while enumerating all of the device interfaces, I decided to test by creating a new file for each one to rule out path format/encoding issues. Here was my output:

```
CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #1.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_1FD2&PID_6103&MI_00&Col02#9&885ad2f&0&0001#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #2.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_046D&PID_C077#6&b39df8e&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x5

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #3.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_B404&PID_0101&MI_01&Col01#7&22822429&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x20

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #4.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_B404&PID_0101&MI_01&Col02#7&22822429&0&0001#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x20

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #5.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_1FD2&PID_6103&MI_01#9&20493974&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #6.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_0424&PID_274C&MI_01#8&2d3dcce0&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #7.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_B404&PID_0101&MI_01&Col03#7&22822429&0&0002#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}\KBD
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x5

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #8.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_B404&PID_0101&MI_00#7&3a45b06e&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}\KBD
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x5

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #9.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_1FD2&PID_6103&MI_00&Col01#9&885ad2f&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x20

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #10.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_00&Col01#8&7741f1a&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #11.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_00&Col02#8&7741f1a&0&0001#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #12.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_01&Col02#8&1f37ab5f&0&0001#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #13.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_01&Col03#8&1f37ab5f&0&0002#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #14.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_02#8&36fb37a4&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #15.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_03#8&1323f9e2&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
CrateFile() worked.

CM_Get_Device_Interface_List() found device #16.
Path: \\?\HID#VID_05AC&PID_0265&MI_01&Col01#8&1f37ab5f&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
THIS is the device we want a file handle for. Path matches what we expect.
CreateFile() failed with error: 0x20
```

The device I'm wanting to connect to (#16 here) is the touchpad. The last several interfaces are associated with the same Apple Trackpad device, and creating a file for them works. The error "ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (0x2)" doesn't make any sense to me.

Here is how I'm creating the file:

```
file_handle = CreateFile( comp_hid_path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
```

According to the MS documentation for OPEN_ALWAYS: "If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero." That implies that this isn't a valid, writable location, but it definitely shows up when enumerating my interfaces.

Am I unable to open a file to the device since it was just sent raw input using WM_INPUT message?

Comment: I think you may need to use `CreateFile(device_path)` to get the handle. Not sure what your device path would be though.

Comment: @JimRhodes I've considered going down that path. I almost think my handle might be correct, but the file might be closed/locked?

Comment: `HidD_GetPreparsedData` require file handle (it must be open and close). the `raw_data_buffer->header.hDevice` not a file handleand of course invalid for `HidD_GetPreparsedData`

Comment: @RbMm thanks for the catch and below example! I ended up trying the following [directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/finding-and-opening-a-hid-collection) and can enumerate through all my connected devices. Do you have any idea how I might be able to programmatically determine which one generated my WM_INPUT message? I don't want to, for example, get preparsed data for every single hid file handle, and compare with what I got from raw_data_buffer->header.hDevice...

Comment: @DannyLovell - you need call `GetRawInputDeviceInfoExW` with `RIDI_DEVICENAME` on `pRawInputDeviceList->hDevice` - it return string - interface name - exactly match to one if strings returned by `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` (i think use CM_ api more simply and of course more efficient compare Setup api (internally it call CM_ api). example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67028399/getrawinputdeviceinfo-indicates-a-buffer-size-of-1-character-for-ridi-devicename/67035589#67035589

Comment: or you can direct use string returned by [`RIDI_DEVICENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdeviceinfow) in call `CreateFileW`

Comment: `with error: 0x20` - `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` - *A file cannot be opened because the share access flags are incompatible.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "handle" is a very generic thing. Any opaque pointer-sized value we can call a "handle".

[`HidD_GetPreparsedData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getpreparseddata) requires a **file handle**. This handle must be **opened** with `CreateFileW` or `NtOpenFile`, `NtCreateFile`. and this handle must be **closed** with `CloseHandle` or `NtClose` once the handle is no longer in use.

The *hDevice* in [`RAWINPUTDEVICELIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rawinputdevicelist) is not a file handle. This is some opaque value, which does not need to be closed. [`GetRawInputDeviceList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdevicelist) returns an array of `RAWINPUTDEVICELIST` and does not say that you need to close *hDevice*.

You can list all hid interfaces in the system by calling [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfgmgr32/nf-cfgmgr32-cm_get_device_interface_listw) with [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-hid). Then pass the returned strings to `CreateFileW` and in this way you get a valid file handle, which can be used when calling `HidD_GetPreparsedData`.

For instance:

```
Enum(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID);

// must be /RTCs-

volatile const UCHAR guz = 0;

void Enum(const GUID* InterfaceClassGuid)
{
    CONFIGRET cr;
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb;
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PZZWSTR Buffer;
    };

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    do 
    {
        cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&rcb, const_cast<GUID*>(InterfaceClassGuid), 0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

        if (cr != CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (cb < (rcb *= sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(const_cast<GUID*>(InterfaceClassGuid), 
            0, Buffer, cb/sizeof(WCHAR), CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

    } while (cr == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    if (cr == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        while (*Buffer)
        {
            DumpInterface(Buffer);
            Buffer += wcslen(Buffer) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

My implementation of `DumpInterface`:

```
void GetPropertyByDeviceID(PCSTR prefix, DEVINST dnDevInst)
{

    HANDLE hFile;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;
    UNICODE_STRING ObjectName;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, &ObjectName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE };


    CONFIGRET status;

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x80;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR sz;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    static struct  
    {
        CONST DEVPROPKEY *PropertyKey;
        PCWSTR PropertyName;
    } PropertyKeys[] = {
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName, L"PDOName"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_Parent, L"Parent"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_DriverVersion, L"DriverVersion"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo, L"LocationInfo"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_FirmwareVersion, L"FirmwareVersion"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_Model, L"Model"},
        { &DEVPKEY_NAME, L"NAME"},
        { &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, L"DeviceID"}
    };

    do 
    {
        int n = RTL_NUMBER_OF(PropertyKeys);

        do 
        {
            CONST DEVPROPKEY *PropertyKey = PropertyKeys[--n].PropertyKey;

            do 
            {
                if (cb < rcb)
                {
                    rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
                }

                status = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, PropertyKey, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

                if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
                    {
                        DbgPrint("%s%S=[%S]\n", prefix, PropertyKeys[n].PropertyName, sz);

                        if (!n)
                        {
                            // DEVPKEY_Device_PDOName can use in NtOpenFile

                            RtlInitUnicodeString(&ObjectName, sz);

                            if (0 <= NtOpenFile(&hFile, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES|SYNCHRONIZE, &oa,
                                &iosb, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT))
                            {
                                NtClose(hFile);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

        } while (n);

        if (!*--prefix) break;

    } while (CM_Get_Parent(&dnDevInst, dnDevInst, 0) == CR_SUCCESS);
}

void DumpInterface(PCWSTR InterfaceLink)
{
    DbgPrint("\r\n--------\r\n%S\r\n\r\n", InterfaceLink);

    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    union {
        PBYTE PropertyBuffer;
        PVOID buf;
        DEVINSTID_W pDeviceID;
        PWSTR PDOName;
    };

    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x80;
    CONFIGRET cr;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        cr = CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW(InterfaceLink, &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, 
            &PropertyType, PropertyBuffer, &(rcb = cb), 0);

    } while (cr == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    DEVINST dnDevInst;

    if (cr == CR_SUCCESS && 
        PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING && 
        CR_SUCCESS == CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, pDeviceID, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL ))
    {
        char prefix[64];
        memset(prefix, '\t', _countof(prefix));
        prefix[_countof(prefix) - 1] = 0;
        //DbgPrint("%S\n", pDeviceID);
        GetPropertyByDeviceID(prefix + _countof(prefix) - 1, dnDevInst);
    }
}
```

---

Or if we have [`RAWINPUTDEVICELIST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdeviceinfow) as input - we can get the device interface name with `RIDI_DEVICENAME`. We can use this name to call `CreateFileW` to get a file handle for the device.

```
ULONG GetRawInputDeviceInfoExW(_In_opt_ HANDLE hDevice, 
                               _In_ UINT uiCommand, 
                               _Inout_updates_bytes_to_opt_(*pcbSize, *pcbSize) LPVOID pData, 
                               _Inout_ PUINT pcbSize)
{
    switch (int i = GetRawInputDeviceInfoW(hDevice, uiCommand, pData, pcbSize))
    {
    case 0:
        return ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER;
    case 1:
        return ERROR_INVALID_NAME;
    default:
        if (0 > i)
        {
            return GetLastError();
        }
        *pcbSize = i;

        return NOERROR;
    }
}

void DemoRI()
{
    PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST pRawInputDeviceList = 0;
    UINT uiNumDevices = 0; 
    UINT cch, cchAllocated = 0;
    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PWSTR name;
    };

    buf = 0;

    while (0 <= (int)GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, &uiNumDevices, sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)))
    {
        if (pRawInputDeviceList)
        {
            do 
            {
                HANDLE hDevice = pRawInputDeviceList->hDevice;

                ULONG dwError;
                while (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == (dwError = 
                    GetRawInputDeviceInfoExW(hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, name, &(cch = cchAllocated))))
                {
                    if (cch > cchAllocated)
                    {
                        cchAllocated = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca((cch - cchAllocated) * sizeof(WCHAR)), 
                            pRawInputDeviceList) / sizeof(WCHAR);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        __debugbreak();
                    }
                }

                if (dwError == NOERROR)
                {
                    DbgPrint("[%p, %x %S]\n", hDevice, pRawInputDeviceList->dwType, name);
                }
                else
                {
                    DbgPrint("error = %u\n", dwError);
                }

            } while (pRawInputDeviceList++, --uiNumDevices);

            break;
        }
        pRawInputDeviceList = (PRAWINPUTDEVICELIST)alloca(uiNumDevices * sizeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));
    }
}
```

Comment: @psmears thank you for pointing out RIDI_DEVICENAME works. I'm still hitting a roadblock with not being able to create a file for the interface I need. About every other HID device interface, including others associated with the same device, work. I've updated the original post with output and more details. I'd appreciate any ideas!

Comment: @DannyLovell: It wasn't me that wrote this answer - I just edited it to fix a few typos. Hopefully user RbMm can help further!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this microsoft sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/d228af5682ed7e9ca512a789a3be3f89a73bef8f/hid/hclient/report.c#L270), you can use `BOOLEAN GetFeature (PHID_DEVICE HidDevice)` to get feature. And wish the sample works for you.